# What version of OSGi specification is implemented in each Apache Felix release?

Tags: osgi, apache-felix

How can I tell which version of the OSGi spec is implemented in each of the Apache Felix releases?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [this](https://felix.apache.org/documentation/development/osgi-specification-implementations.html) page was supposed to tell that, but it's out of date.

Felix core consists of modules and some of them may have a different version of OSGi Core as dependency. The fact that Felix module has older OSGi dependency doesn't have to mean that it's not compatible with newer spec. Maybe the spec hadn't changed anything in this module's field. Felix Framework has also whole OSGi Core code inline embedded in it.

I can't see other option than trust Felix developers and look into description of the Felix Framework release. You can find all releases in the [Felix repo](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf//felix/releases/) and spec compability declaration is in the `pom.xml` in `Bundle-Description` section, e.g. Felix Framework implements R7 since version 6.0.0.